# Fitting on a semi-logarithmic scale and transfering it back to normal?

Tags: python, fft, ifft

I am working with IFFT and have a set of real and imaginary values with their respective frequencies (x-axis). The frequencies are not equidistant, I can't use a discrete IFFT, and I am unable to fit my data correctly, because the values are so jumpy at the beginning. So my plan is to "stretch out" my frequency data points on a lg-scale, fit them (with polyfit) and then return - somehow - to normal scale.

```
f = data[0:27,0]  #x-values
re = daten[0:27,5] #y-values

lgf = p.log10(f)
polylog_re = p.poly1d(p.polyfit(lgf, re, 6))
```

The fit works definitely better (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdPeo.jpg), **but is it possible to then transform my polynom back into the normal x-scaling?** Right now I'm using those logarithmic fits for my IFFT and take the `log10` of my transformed values for plotting etc., but that probably defies all mathematical logic and results in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your fit is perfectly valid but not a regular polynomial fit. By using log_10(x), you use another model function. Something like `y(x)=sum(a_i * 10^(x_i^i)`. If this is okay for you, you are done. When you wan't to do some more maths, I would suggest using the natural logarithm instead the one to base 10.